# vertext failled Error and Mapper initialized failed - Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I'm using Hortonworks data platform in our server with 2 nodes. I'm running query successfully in hive. Suddenly I'm facing mapping with source table to add column to my new table, By this below query; while running this query in hive view. How do I resolve this issue?

```
create table New_table 
As
select distinct
ab.id,
ab.first_name,
ab.middle_name,
ab.last_name,
b.Address,
b.City_Name,
b.State_Name
from Temp_table ab join Source_table b on (ab.id=b.id);
```

I got vertext failled error. Please find my log

```
    × java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1504352268873_0146_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1504352268873_0146_1_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139) at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181) at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149) ... 14 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247) ... 15 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387) ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.nextBufferToWrite(WriteBuffers.java:243) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.write(WriteBuffers.java:219) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinBytesTableContainer$LazyBinaryKvWriter.writeKey(MapJoinBytesTableContainer.java:238) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.BytesBytesMultiHashMap.put(BytesBytesMultiHashMap.java:450) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.internalPutRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:501) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.putRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:449) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92) ... 4 more ], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Container container_e29_1504352268873_0146_01_000012 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=255. Exception from container-launch. Container id: container_e29_1504352268873_0146_01_000012 Exit code: 255 Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255: at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:933) at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:844) at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1123) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:225) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255 ]], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139) at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181) at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149) ... 14 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247) ... 15 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387) ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.nextBufferToWrite(WriteBuffers.java:243) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.write(WriteBuffers.java:219) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinBytesTableContainer$LazyBinaryKvWriter.writeValue(MapJoinBytesTableContainer.java:286) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.BytesBytesMultiHashMap.writeFirstValueRecord(BytesBytesMultiHashMap.java:839) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.BytesBytesMultiHashMap.put(BytesBytesMultiHashMap.java:460) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.internalPutRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:501) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.putRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:449) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92) ... 4 more ], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139) at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185) at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181) at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149) ... 14 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247) ... 15 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387) ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.nextBufferToWrite(WriteBuffers.java:243) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.reserve(WriteBuffers.java:182) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.BytesBytesMultiHashMap.writeFirstValueRecord(BytesBytesMultiHashMap.java:854) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.BytesBytesMultiHashMap.put(BytesBytesMultiHashMap.java:460) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.internalPutRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:501) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.putRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:449) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92) ... 4 more ]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1504352268873_0146_1_01 [Map 2] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 3, vertexId=vertex_1504352268873_0146_1_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:10, Vertex vertex_1504352268873_0146_1_02 [Reducer 3] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1

    java.lang.Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1504352268873_0146_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1504352268873_0146_1_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.nextBufferToWrite(WriteBuffers.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.WriteBuffers.write(WriteBuffers.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinBytesTableContainer$LazyBinaryKvWriter.writeKey(MapJoinBytesTableContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.BytesBytesMultiHashMap.put(BytesBytesMultiHashMap.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.internalPutRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HybridHashTableContainer.putRow(HybridHashTableContainer.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
    ... 4 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Container container_e29_1504352268873_0146_01_000012 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=255. Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e29_1504352268873_0146_01_000012
Exit code: 255
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255
]], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Map operator initialization failed with OOM exception. Try to increase memory per mapper container:

```
set hive.tez.container.size=2048;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx1700m;  --set this 80% of hive.tez.container.size
```